# FSharp - Unexpected behaviour with match and returning records based on array

Tags: f#

I'm just really getting into FSharp and I've been struggling with this for quite a while because I cannot understand why I'm not getting my expected results on the match statement.

Based on the message number, I need to match certain values in the array (splits) to fields on the record that I want to return.

```
let UNMATCHED = "UNMATCHED"
let T0200 = "T0200" ;; let R0200 = "R0200"

let matchTypes = [| { MessageType = T0200; Regex = REGEX_T0200 }
                ; { MessageType = R0200; Regex = REGEX_R0200 }
...

let messageInfo (matchType:MatchType, line:string) =
    let matching = Regex.Match(line, REGEX_DATA)
    let splits = matching.Value.Replace("[","").Replace("]","").Split('|')
    let showSplit (x:string[]) = "[" + String.Join(";",x) + "]"
    let info =
        Console.WriteLine("matching against: " + matchType.MessageType)
        match matchType.MessageType with
            | T0200 -> 
                { MessageType = T0200; CustomerID = splits.[1]; CustomerName = "";
                        ItemID = splits.[2]; ItemDescription = "" }
            | R0200 ->
                { MessageType = R0200; CustomerID = splits.[1]; CustomerName = splits.[2];
                        ItemID = splits.[5]; ItemDescription = splits.[6] }
            ...
            | UNMATCHED ->  { MessageType = UNMATCHED; CustomerID = ""; CustomerName = "";
                        ItemID = ""; ItemDescription = "" }
            | _ ->  { MessageType = UNMATCHED; CustomerID = ""; CustomerName = "";
                        ItemID = ""; ItemDescription = "" }
    Console.WriteLine("messageInfo: {0}", (matchType, showSplit splits, info))
    info
```

However, this does not seem to work and from the output below, I get the expected result for the T0200 however for R0200 the mapping of the fields does not match to fields in the array - ie. it seems to use the same array indices as the T0200 statement. I have the exact same problem on all other subsequent messages.

```
matching against: T0200
messageInfo: ({MessageType = "T0200";
 Regex = "\sT0200\[([\w\s]*\|)*[\w\s]*\]";}, [3;000008757051;1401], {MessageType = "T0200";
 CustomerID = "000008757051";
 CustomerName = "";
 ItemID = "1401";
 ItemDescription = "";})
matching against: R0200
messageInfo: ({MessageType = "R0200";
 Regex = "\sR0200\[([\w\s]*\|)*[\w\s]*\]";}, [3;000008757051;Ricky Bobby;413792;0;1401;SNACKER;909;0], {MessageType = "R0200";
 CustomerID = "000008757051";
 CustomerName = "";
 ItemID = "Ricky Bobby";
 ItemDescription = "";})
```

I'm guessing there's something wrong the syntax on my match statement - what am I doing wrong?

I'm running on dotnet core 2.0.2 on ubuntu

Thanks

Comment: what's the diff between `UNMATCHED` and `_`? You suppose to use underscore for "all the other cases". BTW, `.NET` on linux is a pain: move to Haskell. `F#` is nothing but a poor copy of `Haskell`.

Comment: I probably don't need the UNMATCHED - it was just for other message types that I'm not interested in. I looked at Haskell but I found it a bit scary :) - I've done most of my dev in csharp

Comment: Can you show the definition of `T0200` in your code?

Comment: I edited - please check now - they are just strings. Thanks

Comment: @onemorecupofcoffee, as long as you do understand `F#`, you'll definitely understand the `Haskell`'s basics. More advanced stuff takes time to master, however then you do understand the root of ideas emerging everywhere starting from `C#` and ending up with `F#`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MessageType` is a string and `T0200` is just a named string value. When you try to match on `T0200` it's actually binding the string to `T0200` and the always going into the first branch of your `match`. The pattern matching language doesn't allow you to match on value names like that. You can match on discriminated union cases, literal values and a few other things. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/pattern-matching).

Comment: cool, thanks for that - everything seemed to be going through the first branch but I didn't understand why

Comment: @onemorecupofcoffee There are a few different ways you could take it now. You could change define a discriminated union `type MessageType = T0200 | R0200` instead of using strings. This way your pattern matching would work.